# Mysql - Insert multiple unique rows without a unique key

Tags: mysql, database, insert, unique, subquery

I have a question regarding a budgeting application I am writing.  I regularly import transactions from my bank into a mysql database.  I am doing this through a "download transaction" feature of my online bank where I get a list of transactions based on a date range that I select.  For my application to work it is crucial that my database does not include duplicate transactions.  The downloaded transaction list comes in this format

- Date,Description,Amount,Running Bal.

So as you can see the kicker is that my debit card transactions do not have a unique reference id!  This drives me crazy because my downloaded credit transactions from the same bank DO have a unique reference id but my debit card transactions do not.  So what I want is to take a group of transactions (usually like 20 or so) and construct one mysql insert query that inserts transactions from that group that have a unique combination of date, desc, amt, and balance. So for example let’s say the downloaded statement from my bank has these five transactions:

- 12/20/2019  Gift for Joe       5.00       10000.00
- 12/20/2019  Paint              10.00      9990.00
- 12/21/2019  Hamburger place    20.00      9970.00
- 12/21/2019  Electric Bill      100.00     9870.00
- 12/21/2019  Movie              10.00      9860.00

And the mysql database already has

- 12/20/2019  Gift for Joe     5.00        10000.00
- 12/20/2019  Paint              10.00       9990.00

Then I only want to insert

- 12/21/2019  Hamburger place    20.00     9970.00
- 12/21/2019  Electric Bill      100.00    9870.00
- 12/21/2019  Movie              10.00     9860.00

Basically I only want to insert unique rows into my database and because BoA does not provide a unique id I need additional logic to determine uniqueness.  Can you please give me guidance on how to construct this mysql query?  If you could even point me to a relevant tutorial it would be much appreciated!  Thank you all.

Answer (score 0):

If `table1` is the table where you want to insert the new rows and `table2` the table that contains the new rows to be inserted you can use `NOT EXISTS`:

```
insert into table1(Date, Description, Amount, RunningBal)
select t2.Date, t2.Description, t2.Amount, t2.RunningBal
from table2 t2
where not exists (
  select 1 from table1 t1
  where t1.Date = t2.Date and t1.Description = t2.Description
    and t1.Amount = t2.Amount and t1.RunningBal = t2.RunningBal
)
```